# local variable referenced before assignment but its not

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
        # Get .webpfile
        for file in os.listdir(selected_folder):
            if file.endswith(".webp"):
                webp_path = os.path.join(selected_folder, file)
                webp_name = os.path.join(file)
                


        # Convert .webp to .jpg because YouTube doesn't like .webp :/
        im = Image.open(webp_path).convert("RGB")
        im.save(webp_path + ".jpg","jpeg")
```

I'm getting

```
local variable 'webp_path' referenced before assignment
```

and if I put global, it says that webp_path doesn't exist

Comment: `webp_path` only exists if your `if` condition is true. It likely isn't, meaning it _is_ being referenced before assignment.

Comment: ```webp_path``` is defined only if certain conditions are met. But ```Image.open(webp_path)``` is executed regardless of whether it is defined or not. Hence the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to access `web_path` in your code, however web_path is getting initialized under the if-block in your for-loop.
So there can be a chance that it might never get initialized. Also, there can be more than one file that ends with .webp, so I'd suggest keeping the image conversion logic under the for-loop. This will fix your code:

```py
       # Get .webpfile
        for file in os.listdir(selected_folder):
            if file.endswith(".webp"):
                webp_path = os.path.join(selected_folder, file)
                webp_name = os.path.join(file)
            else:
                continue
                
            # Convert .webp to .jpg because YouTube doesn't like .webp :/
            im = Image.open(webp_path).convert("RGB")
            im.save(webp_path + ".jpg","jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because there `web_path` is defined in your conditions but when some condition is True only but your `Image.open(webp_path)` executing when there is not `web_path` also.

You can try this to resolve your problem:

```
for file in os.listdir(selected_folder):
    if file.endswith(".webp"):
        webp_path = os.path.join(selected_folder, file)
        webp_name = os.path.join(file)

if web_path:
    im = Image.open(webp_path).convert("RGB")
    im.save(webp_path + ".jpg","jpeg")
```

Or `try-expect`, if you don't need anything to do if that if condition don't met:

```
for file in os.listdir(selected_folder):
    if file.endswith(".webp"):
        webp_path = os.path.join(selected_folder, file)
        webp_name = os.path.join(file)
try:
    im = Image.open(webp_path).convert("RGB")
    im.save(webp_path + ".jpg","jpeg")
except:
    pass
```